# Number of ways to divide an array into two subsets of equal sum

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Question:
You have been given an array of values. You must split between two people A and B such that:

1. The total sum of values given to A is exactly equal to the total sum of values given to B.
2. They both should get at least one value.
3. There can be some values left undistributed.

Input: The array of values.

Output: Determine the number of ways such distribution can be made.

Example:

```
Input:[1,2,3,4,5,11]
Answer:8
Possible answers: 
[2,3][5]     
[3,4][5,2]
[2,4,5][11] 
[3,4,5][1,11]
[1,2,3,5][11]
[1,2][3]
[1,3][4]
[1,4][5]
```

It was asked to me in an Interview. I was able to solve it in O(n * range_of_sum * range_of_sum) using Dynamic Programming. But the interviewer was looking for a better approach in terms of time complexity(probably O(n * range_of_sum)).

Comment: What makes you think that there is a better approach in terms of time complexity than that?

Comment: Because this question was asked to me in an interview and he was expecting a more optimized approach.

Comment: I edited my post and mentioned the same in it.

Comment: O(n * range * range) is O(n) time. So the only way you could improve this is to make it O(log(n)) or O(1). I can't think of a way to do that but there may be one. It's possible the interviewer was looking for a better average-case time instead of better worst-case time.

Comment: I am sorry but how is O (n * range * range ) is O(n)? Let's say the number of elements in an array is 1000, and the maximum possible sum of all elements in 2000, so I gave him a solution that will run in O(1000 * 2000 * 2000) in the worst case and he was expecting me to make it run in O(1000 * 2000) in the worst case. I hope, I am clear on this. Thanks!

Comment: `O(1000 * 2000 * 2000)` This notation makes little sense. `O(1000 * 2000 * 2000)` is exactly the same as `O(1)`. I understand your intention but the execution is wrong.

Comment: @LayneBernardo *O(n * range * range) is O(n) time* Nope.

Comment: Big O notation sets an upper bound as n goes to a very large number. This means we can *discard* any constants. The range of the values is a *constant*. Therefore what we have is O(n*c^2). We can drop c^2, since, as I said, it is constant. Therefore this is O(n) time.

Comment: I think you may be confusing Big-O notation with Little-o notation.

Comment: @LayneBernardo Yeah, I got your point. The range of sum is constant and with big O we can ignore constants. I got a little confused because I wanted a more optimized solution in terms of overall operations done. Anyway, I found the answer, Thanks!

Comment: @LayneBernardo "The range of the values is a constant". Says who?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that he was probably looking for is to fill out the following structure.

```
By Sum(A) - Sum(B)
  By whether A has any values
    By whether B has any values
      Count of ways to get here
```

For `n` steps you have to fill out a data structure of size `O(range_of_sum)` making for memory use `O(range_of_sum)` and time `O(n * range_of_sum)`.

Comment: Thank You so much, I think I got your answer. I need to maintain only one sum variable and if I give value to A, I will increase sum by a[i], and if I give value to B, I should decrease sum by a[i], and the final condition should be to check whether the sum is equal to 0 or not, right? Indeed, the time complexity will be O(n * range_of_sum).

Comment: @SuspiciousKitchen-7 Exactly.